# Extract Url From a String

Tags: ruby

I have a URL:

```
url = "http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/fy/8at2EuL0ihSIb3s7/story01.htmA"
```

There are some unwanted characters like A,TRE, at the end. I want to remove this so the URL will be like this:

```
url = http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/fy/8at2EuL0ihSIb3s7/story01.htm
```

How can I remove them?

Comment: What have you done by far?

Comment: i have parsed data from a string using nokogiri when i parsed url then i get url something like this  url="http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/fy/8at2EuL0ihSIb3s7/story01.htmA" but the original url is url="http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/fy/8at2EuL0ihSIb3s7/story01.htm"    please help me

Comment: So ,you need to remove after .htm? right?

Comment: unwanted charecter like(A,TRE,) etc..  here in URL where is TRE?

Comment: yes but it not sure anything in url like .php,or .aspx etc

Comment: TRE just example (Unwanted charecter in my urls i have thousands url all have some extra charecter please help me )

Comment: You need to declare an array and that array should contain all type of file formats.(.php,.htm,.aspx like...) , then you can use split method.

Comment: A good question is WHY are those showing up? I suspect the page has a multibyte encoding that isn't being accounted for. Fix that and the URLs should clean up by themselves. What is the source URL you are parsing to get the sub-URLs?

Comment: Also, don't plead for help in your question and comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your url always finish with `.htm`, `.apsx` or `.php` you can solve it with a simple regex:

```
url = url[/^(.+\.(htm|aspx|php))(:?.*)$/, 1]
```

Tests [**here at Rubular**](http://rubular.com/r/bgZJUbWkEY).

First I use [**this method**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) to get a substring, works like slice. Then comes the regex. From left to right:

```
^                   # Start of line
  (                   # Capture everything wanted enclosed
    .+                  # 1 or more of any character
    \.                  # With a dot after it
    (htm|aspx|php)      # htm or aspx or php
  )                   # Close url asked in question
  (                   # Capture undesirable part
    :?                  # Optional
    .*                  # 0 or more any character
  )                   # Close undesirable part
$                   # End of line
```

Comment: that is a better answer, @waldyr.ar could you please explain how it works?

Comment: I was afraid you didn't like it. Better than expected! @shweta