# Extract URL from a string?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract Url From a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257111/extract-url-from-a-string)

I have a string like:

```
abchghhdgfdgfdfdfhttp://www.rajasthanpatrika.com/News/World/1132013/international news/414309\r\n\t\t\t\t     ghjghjfhjvfhjhfj"
```

I want to extract the URL:

```
http://www.rajasthanpatrika.com/News/World/1132013/international news/414309
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why nokogiri? There's no html or xml.

Comment: URLs can't have spaces in them.

Comment: url have space in rajsthan patrika I am also socked with this

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257111/extract-url-from-a-string

Comment: Sir My title is same but my problem is diffent here because here url have some space so i have face the problem

Comment: It's still the same problem, with a little different sample data. A correct solution for the first will solve this one also. A better question is, what are you doing that causes such sample data -- I have never seen anything look like that unless I'm doing something very wrong extracting the data. Cleaning up your data will go a long way to making your URLs easy to extract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = "abchghhdgfdgfdfdfhttp://www.rajasthanpatrika.com/News/World/1132013/international news/414309\r\n\t\t\t\t ghjghjfhjvfhjhfj"
s[/http:\/\/.*?(?=[\r\n\t])/]
# => "http://www.rajasthanpatrika.com/News/World/1132013/international news/414309"
```

Comment: wow I had no idea strings would do [/regex/]. Ruby never ceases to have more wrinkles... :)